# Sum two NSInteger gives incorrect result

Tags: objective-c

Im haveing a problem suming two NSInteger, I have tried with simple int but cant find the answer. I Have this on my header file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
NSMutableArray *welcomePhotos;
NSInteger *photoCount;        // <- this is the number with the problem
//static int photoCount = 1;
}
```

The on my implementation fiel I have:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    photoCount = 0;
    welcomePhotos = [NSMutableArray array];


    int sum = photoCount + 1;

    NSLog(@"0 + 1 = %i", sum);

}
```

The las NSLog always prints **0 + 1 = 4**

Also if if do:

```
if (photoCount < [welcomePhotos count]){
    photoCount++;
    NSLog(@"%i", photoCount);
}else{
    photoCount = 0;
}
```

Several times i get: **4, 8, 12**.

So it is skiping by four, but I can't get to understand why.

Comment: The problem is that you've declared `photoCount` to be a pointer to an  `NSInteger`.  Remember that `NSInteger` is a typedef for signed integer (32-bit or 64-bit depending on the system).

Comment: maybe because NSInteger is a special int that takes different values at runtime according to the number of bits of your plateform (32 bits or 64 bits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing out a pointer object I believe as you've declared it as

```
NSInteger* photocount;
```

Try changing it to

```
int photocount;
```

doing a variable++ on an integer adds the size of a pointer which is 4 bytes on iOS.

Comment: why not `NSInteger photocount;`?

Answer (score 5):

You are declaring your `photoCount` instance var as *pointer* to `NSInteger`.  But NSInteger is a scalar type.
Remove the asterisk in your .h file and try again.

Replace

```
NSInteger *photoCount;
```

with

```
NSInteger photoCount;
```

Comment: Best answer but a minute late ;)

Answer (score 3):

You used pointer to `NSInteger`...

Change it to `NSInteger photoCount;`

NSInteger is just an int, and you are treating it as an wrapper object. Pointer in not required.